# CSS not working correctly in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a method, using the list elements id, to change the color of a menu button depending on the current page. If it does not match the current page then the id is set to the default string. It works in Chrome but doesn't work in FireFox. Let me know if I need to add more code.

In Master Page

```
<div id="body">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" />
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu_wrap" class="Blue">
                <li class="button" id="<%= SetSelectedLink("Default.aspx") %>"><a href="Default.aspx">Manage Report</a></li>
                <li class="button" id="<%= SetSelectedLink("Item.aspx") %>"><a href="Item.aspx">Create New Item</a></li>
                <li class="button" id="<%= SetSelectedLink("CloneReport.aspx") %>"><a href="CloneReport.aspx">Clone Report</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

In Master.cs file

```
public string SetSelectedLink(string linkUrl)
    {
        var url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower();
        return url.Contains(linkUrl.ToLower()) ? "temp" : "";
    }
```

In the Css file

```
li#temp.button a {
    background: #0078a5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0078a5 0%, #00adee 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0078a5), color-stop(100%,#00adee));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0078a5 0%,#00adee 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0078a5 0%,#00adee 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0078a5 0%,#00adee 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0078a5', endColorstr='#00adee',GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(top, #0078a5 0%,#00adee 100%);
}
```

Comment: Please post the resulting html instead of the asp code.

Comment: Why are you using an id and not a class?

Comment: @epascarello I thought this would be the best way to handle it?

Comment: Most developers use the class "active" or "selected" seems weird to use an id that is controlling style.

Comment: @user3339242, ID is okay but class will be better. You can just rename your method to `SetSelectedClass` and just output the class name. Same concept as you are doing now.

Comment: @user3339242 Be aware that `id`s must be unique. I would get rid of them and use the selector `#menu_wrap > li > a`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is obsolete:

```css
linear-gradient(top, #0078a5 0%,#00adee 100%);
```

The new syntax is

```css
linear-gradient(to bottom, #0078a5 0%,#00adee 100%);
```

See [History of the syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#History_of_the_syntax) and [Cross-browser gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Cross-browser_gradients) in MDN article.